# UnmanagedExport dll does not create export table

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I've been trying to make a C# dll with C style API (export table). And I've made this most easy code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace CS_Post
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [DllExport("ABC", CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hehe");
        }
    }
}
```

And when I dump this dll I get:

```
E:\Projects\CS_Post\bin\Release>dumpbin \exports CS_Post.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24213.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file CS_Post.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .text
```

Also it works only on .NET 3.5, any higher seems can't find `ildasm.exe`

```
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper could not find ildasm.exe
```

I am not even able to find any working example for this UnamanagedExports.
Can someone help getting this done? For now I just want to export a single function/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was - You cannot have set Mixed Platform in project build. It has to be either x64 or x86. Works fine even for newest .NET.